# Toyota 04 Camry

Tags: toyota, clutch, repair, camry, clutch-hydraulics

please help 
Changed clutch and slave cylinder 
Trying to bleed it but just air bubbles 
Can't see any leaks 
It's a 2004 Camry 
Could it be the booster ?

Comment: Did you actually change the clutch, or the master/slave for the clutch? Also, did you bench bleed your hydraulics prior to putting it on the car? I don't think there is a clutch master booster (like a brake system; I've never seen one) so I doubt that is at issue.